# How to connect multiple displays on a laptop with multiple graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have an MSI GE70 2OE laptop. It has both an Intel HD Graphics 4600 and NVIDIA GTX 765M graphics card. It uses Intel graphics by default and only starts to use 765M on gaming or video related stuff automatically.

The laptop has an HDMI port and a VGA port.

I want to connect 3 external monitors to it, so that I'll be using 3 external monitors without the built in laptop monitor. How can I do that?

P.S. From my research I've seen that GTX 765M has support for 3 displays. But NVIDIA control panel does not show display options, probably because display options are handled by Intel graphics by default.

Answer (score 0):

As you only have those two ports, you can only connect two displays. Very few laptops will support a third.

The NVidia GTX 765M chipset may support, in fact, 4 displays… but NVidia don't make the graphics cards, only the chipset, so you have what MSI gave you instead… which is two external displays.
Your laptop will probably slow to a crawl & run hot even with just the two, as what's driving it is really the HD4600 chipset, to which the 765M is, in effect, a slave..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking connecting the third monitor by a usb display adapter, but I am not sure HD4600 will support 3 displays even If I am able to connect 3 monitors physically

Comment: I need to first say that @Tetsujin is *mostly* on the money.  I have the same configuration on an HP laptop.  I was able to get two monitors to work JUST FINE.. as in coded for hours and hours every single day without a hiccup or noticeable frame rate loss or overheating.  When I went to 3 displays (just like you), there wasn't enough video memory to support it.  If you want to play with this option, use the intel gfx control panel and not the nvidia one.  The "intel side" controls the bigger picture of how the monitor layout works.